# Instances of classes

Tags: java

Does a non-static method create an instance of the class in which it is declared? If not why this code works?

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Frame {
    public Main () {
       //super keyword needs an istance of the class don't it?
       super ("My frame");
       super.setSize (200,100); 
    }

    public static void main (String [ ] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

If a non-static method creates an instance of the class the next code should work...

```
import.java.applet.*;

public class Main extends Applet {
    public void print () {
       System.out.println ("Hi");
    }

    public void init () {
        this.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Once `Main()` is called, you are in an instance, one that is being created by the call...

Comment: `Main()` is a constructor, _not_ a non-static method.

Comment: Oh well... right. What about the second code does it work? If yes why?

Answer (score 2):

A non-static method *can only be accessed* in the context of an instance that *already exists*.

```
public class Foo {  
  public static void someStaticMethod() { /* ... */ }

  public void someNonStaticMethod() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
Foo.someStaticMethod(); // this works
Foo.someNonStaticMethod(); // this DOESN'T work

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.someNonStaticMethod(); // but this does
```

Within a non-static method, you have access to an instance by default (implicitly), or can refer to it explicitly using the `this` keyword. In your example:

```
public class Main extends Frame {
  public Main () {
    //super keyword needs an istance of the class don't it?
    super ("My frame");
    super.setSize (200,100); 
  }

  public static void main (String [ ] args) {
    new Main();
  }
}
```

...the instance in question in the call to `super` is the implicit instance you create with `new Main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instances of classes in Java are created by calling a constructor using the `new` keyword:

```
Main main = new Main();
```

`public void Main () { }` however is **not a constructor, but a instance method** (which, in your example, never gets called).

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main(); // create instance
        main.Main(); // call method 'Main'
        new Main().Main(); // or both at once
    }

    public Main() {
        // this is the (default) constructor
    }

    public void Main() {
        // this is an instance method (whose name 'should' start lowercase
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does a non-static method create an instance of the class in which it is declared?

No.

> why this code works?

Because when such a method is called, it should be called from an already instantiated instance.  "this"/"super" refer to the implicit parameter, which is the instance in question (instantiated and passed in from elsewhere, with "new").  If instantiation has not occurred, a NullPointerException will immediately be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually in the main question I wrote a wrong code (I've been out for all the day and I'm quite tired) anyway it helped me to understand more. Now what about this code

```
import java.applet.*; 

public class Main extends Applet {
        //overrides Applet.init ()
        public void init () { 
          //here I use super keyword without creating an istance of the class 
            super.init (); 
            //code here... 
         } 
}
```

Comment: Well, you shouldn't put your question as answer and I shouldnt be writing answer to answer in the comment, ... well what the heck :  this works. You simply overriding behavior of `Applet`'s init method  and internally call `init` of `Applet` superclass first.   This is standard practice.   Eventually, when you have instance of `Main` you will call your `init` on it :   `Main m = new Main();`  `m.init()`;

Comment: Yes sorry for the question in the answers. Anyway super keyword doesn't need an istance to work?

Comment: You are confused. When you are inside your `instance` method (i.e. non-static method of the class) - `init` is an instance method above, you are always having `instance` of that class, which you can refer to by `this`. You can also refer to `parent`, i.e. inherited functionality by using `super`.

Comment: Ok now I understand, obviously (actually not for me) if a method is not-static to be called needs an istance of the class so non-static methods have always a istance of the class (but they don't create one). Now I had a new question: where is the init method called?

Comment: Yes, `instance` method is called only for a given `instance` of the class. Where `init` is called depends on where you call it (nobody calls it in your code). So, first create instance of Main: `Main m = new Main();` then call method _on that instance_ : `m.init();`

Comment: I really recommend you go thru tutorial quickly, you'll have tons of things [clarified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)